# Python 3.4: Lists stored in a file - Iterating over characters instead of list items

Tags: python

I have a file (myfile) like this

```
['user1', 1,2]
['user2',5,1]
['user3',1,2]
```

I want to iterate for each items in the list from file. My code is below

```
with open(myfile) as f:
    for line in f:
        for items in list(line):
            print(items)
```

It prints each characters instead of each word. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reading the lines as strings, not as lists. `eval()` or `ast.literal_eval()` for more security should do the trick here:

```
with open(myfile) as f:
    for line in f:
        for items in eval(line):
            print(items)
```

or more secure (thanks to @JaredGoguen):

```
import ast
with open(myfile) as f:
    for line in f:
        for items in ast.literal_eval(line):
            print(items)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: `eval` is evil... It would be better to use `ast.literal_eval` or `json.loads` (if possible)

Comment: @JaredGoguen Thanks for that, fixed!